# How can I adjust my function so the page editor still loads in the backend?

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I have a live search function which fetches WooCommerce products in realtime.

It works perfectly in the front end, however I notice there is a conflict which blocks my WordPress Editor plugin- Brizy from loading within the CMS.

```
 function ajax_fetch() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Therefore I edit the function to allow me to edit pages:

```
    function ajax_fetch() {
    if ( isset( $_GET[ Brizy_Editor::prefix('-edit-iframe') ] ) || isset( $_GET[ Brizy_Editor::prefix('-edit') ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

My update means I can use my page editor, but now my search function doesn't work.

How can I adjust my code so my search still works correctly and I can load the page editor in the CMS?

Added for context: The second half of my query in functions.php(unchanged in both statements)

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){


    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $count = 1; while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $count %4 == 1 ) {  
             echo '<div class="row"">';
        }

        global $product;
        $product = get_product( get_the_ID() ); //set the global product object
    
        $myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
        $a = $myquery;
        $search = get_the_title();
        if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php
if( $text = get_field( 'product_overlay_text', $product->get_id() )  ){
        echo '<p class="prod-overlay prod-overlay-text">' . $text . '</p>';
    }
                            ?>                    
            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); //ouptput the woocommerce loop add to cart button ?>
         
<?php
                                  }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Front end script

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()">

<div id="datafetch">Your numbers will show here</div>



<script>
function fetch(){

$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'my_action'},
function(response){
    $('#datafetch').append(response);
    console.log(result);
});
}
</script>
```

**Edit: Checking Console, I see the following error related to my front page code:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ((index):129)

This relates to:

```
<p><input type="partitioned" name="keyword" id="keyword" maxlength="6" onkeyup="fetch()"></p>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on where your original ajax_fetch() function is being used, but have you tried wrapping your code in the is_admin() conditional, so that the search function only runs on the frontend of the site and not in the control panel at all? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

Comment: @Michelle The logic for your method makes sense, will try this I have added some additional code for context.

Comment: @Michelle adding according to the codex docs did not work for me.

Comment: @P.Sav "Checking Console, I see the following error" - [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (or `window.fetch()`) is a native JS function, so if your function is in the global scope and unless you have a very good reason in overriding `fetch`, you should rename your custom function, e.g. `myFetch`, `fetchData`, etc. and then use that on your `onclick`.